# POWERSHELL - Module Active Directory command New-AdGroup Problem with Spaces in value OU="Servers Of Files"

Tags: powershell, module, active-directory

I would need your help with the use of New-AdGroup command.

The goal of my script is to verify if an Active Directory group exists and if it doesn't exist the script create the group and add the member of the group in a specific OU.

But my problem is when I use the script with a combination of OU and one of them contains some spaces in its name (ex : "OU=Servers of Files"), the script returns an error.

Example: I need to add the group in "OU=Fileserver1" which is a sub OU of "OU=Servers of Files" which is a sub OU of "OU=Groupes".
When I call New-AdGroup with a path's value : "Ou=ServerFile1,OU=Servers of Files,OU=Groupes,DC=Contoso,DC=lan", I get the following error.

> New-ADGroup : Objet de l’annuaire non trouvé At line:29 char:5
>   +     New-ADGroup -Name "$DLGroupName" -Path "$Orga" -GroupCategory "Se ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=G_GROUP1...ONTOSO,DC=lan:String) [New-ADGroup],
>   ADIdentityNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Objet de l’annuaire non trouvé,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup

The problem is caused by "OU=Servers of Files" because I tried with an OU without spaces and it was working.

Please find a part of the script below, let me know how I can manage spaces under a path :

```
#Variable    
$CurrentDomain = Get-ADDomain | Select -Property DistinguishedName
$TargetOU = "OU=FileServer1,OU=Servers of Files,OU=Groupes" #
$OrganizationalUnitDN = $TargetOU+","+ $CurrentDomain.DistinguishedName
$Orga = $OrganizationalUnitDN
$DLGroupName = "DL_FileServer1_TEST"
$Description = "\\FileServer1\Share\Test"


    New-ADGroup -Name "$DLGroupName" -Path "$Orga" -GroupCategory "Security" -GroupScope "Global" -Description "$Description" -PassThru
```

Note : $Orga = Ou=ServerFile1,OU=Servers of Files,OU=Groupes,DC=Contoso,DC=lan

Comment: When you're passing variables into parameters, try not enclosing them in quotes, e.g.: New-ADGroup -Name $DLGroupName -Path $Orga -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have already tried this and it is still not working.

Comment: I obtain this error :  New-ADGroup : Objet de l’annuaire non trouvé
At line:29 char:5
+     New-ADGroup -Name $DLGroupName -Path $Orga -GroupCategory Securit ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=FILEServer1_...ONTOSO,DC=lan:String) [New-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Objet de l’annuaire non trouvé,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup

Comment: Have you tried escaping the spaces with a backslash? `"OU=FileServer1,OU=Servers\ of\ Files,OU=Groupes"`?

Comment: Yes, and the result is the same

Comment: I cannot personally verify this, but https://4sysops.com/forums/topic/new-user-creation/#post-28799 suggests that you must selectively enclose OUs with spaces in single quotes: `"OU=FileServer1,'OU=Servers of Files',OU=Groupes"`

Comment: I also tried this but the result is the same.

Comment: My Powershell version : PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005

Comment: Try replacing the spaces with `\20`. If that too doesn't work, there is something else amiss with the path. The error shows `CN=Fileserver1` , not `OU=Fileserver1`..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried to replacing spaces $Orga = Ou=ServerFile1,OU=Servers\20of\20Files,OU=Groupes,DC=Contoso,DC=lan like this and the result is the same. the error is : New-ADGroup : Objet de l’annuaire non trouvé
At line:29 char:5
+     New-ADGroup -Name $DLGroupName -Path $Orga -GroupCategory Securit ...
+     
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=DL_FileServer1_TEST_...ontoso,DC=lan:String) [New-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Objet de l’annuaire non trouvé,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we encounter weird bugs like this, a good first test is to manually run the command with no variables to find the root cause of the error.  Doing this shows us that we don't need to escape spaces with a `\` or `\20` sequence and that route won't help us.

Because I can run your command with no errors when I manually expand the variables like so:

```
New-ADGroup -Name "DL_FileServer1_TEST" -Path "OU=Servers Of Files,DC=FoxDeploy,DC=local" `
   -GroupCategory "Security" -GroupScope "Global" -Description "Test" -PassThru


DistinguishedName : CN=DL_FileServer1_TEST1,OU=Servers Of Files,DC=FoxDeploy,DC=local
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Global
Name              : DL_FileServer1_TEST1
ObjectClass       : group
ObjectGUID        : 5889f8ea-9d80-4609-ad47-92e50a574088
SamAccountName    : DL_FileServer1_TEST1
SID               : S-1-5-21-3818945699-900446794-3716848007-32100
```

Now that I know this works, I know I can then store the values in variables to make it cleaner to read, like this:

```
$params = @{
    Name = "DL_FileServer1_TEST1";
    Path = "OU=Servers Of Files,DC=FoxDeploy,DC=local";
    GroupCategory = "Security";
    GroupScope = "Global";
    Description = "My Test Group"
    PassThru = $true 
    }

New-ADGroup @params
```

If I had to guess, I bet that you need to run the entire script to populate all of the variables, and instead you are rerunning the last command over and over but one of the variables is `$null`.

**If that doesn't work...**
If not that, then are we sure the container of `Ou=ServerFile1` actually exists too?

Comment: +1 Thank you! for your help. Your information allowed me to solve the problem. the problem was caused by a wrong character. 
It was below my eyes